Best practices for enum with django models and migrations
I have a django model with a field that uses a enum for it's choices tuple like this:
VERSION_CHOICES = tuple(
    (v.value, v.value) for v in ForwardsUpdateEventSensitivityVersion
)
version = models.CharField(
    max_length=max(len(s[0]) for s in VERSION_CHOICES),
    choices=VERSION_CHOICES,
)

What is the best practice for writing the accompanying migration?
Using the enum directly like this:
models.CharField(
    choices=[
        tuple(
            (v.value, v.value)
            for v in ForwardsUpdateEventSensitivityVersion
        )
    ],
)

Or hardcoding the values like this:
models.CharField(
    choices=[("V1", "V1"), ("V2", "V2")],
)


"What is the best practice for writing the accompanying migration?" Why are you even writing that migration manually? makemigrations should be able to generate that for you automatically.

I like to use makemigrations as a starter, but I always check that it makes the intended changes. It does not do a good job of handling things like custom data migrations, complex field renames, or specific issues that arise from the order of field changes.

Hardcoding the values is preferable, because then the migration is a self-contained script and doesn't have a library dependency to import.
Importing application code during a migration can be problematic, because the code (and most importantly the models) may have shifted.
